# Resources to learn GNOME Application Programming for MFC Programmer?

Tags: linux, gnome

I have couple of years of MFC Programming experiance and now want to learn Gnome Application programming. will you please provide me books or reference for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into Mono(C#) for building Gnome Applications. [This link](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_for_Gnome_Applications) might be useful to you.

Also "[Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)" could be your IDE of choice since it allows you to build Gnome apps(GTK) visually

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official gnome developer documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/), I would start by reading the guides.